# how to assign device id (COMn or LTPn) in a variable in batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

The `device ID` for printer I am getting and assigning it to a variable `printerPort`

```bat
for /f "tokens=* skip=1" %%a in ('wmic path Win32_SerialPort get DeviceID') do set printerPort=%%a

echo %printerPort%
```

Output :

```
set printerPort=COM1
set printerPort=
echo
```

How to get device Id **COM1** in variable `printerPort`?

Comment: What is the output of your command `wmic path Win32_SerialPort get DeviceID` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is just the commands in your batch file being echoed. You can see the loop runs twice. You need to come out after the first line:

```
for /f "tokens=* skip=1" %%a in ('wmic path Win32_SerialPort get DeviceID') do (
    set printerPort=%%a
    goto exit1
)
:exit1
echo %printerPort%
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two mentions with your question, the first is that the output you have given does not match what your code will output. The second is that WMIC outputs with a non standard line feed/carriage return sequence, the most efficient way to counter this is to pass the result through another loop.

Either like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC Path Win32_SerialPort Get DeviceID'
) Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "printerPort=%%B"

Echo %printerPort%
```

Or sometimes, *(in this case)*, like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC Path Win32_SerialPort Get DeviceID'
) Do For %%B In (%%A) Do Set "printerPort=%%B"

Echo %printerPort%
```